# Is it possible at this point to use Nuodb as a "drop-in" replacement for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, nuodb

I have completed a  quick start tutorial  for Zend Framework where MySQL is replaced by Nuodb without changing a line of code or at least to my recollection no DB queries where changed. The quick start being a very simplistic application i understand that it is possible, but when you have more complexe queries, views, stored proc. etc... I am prerrty sure it's another ball game! Is NuoDb a viable drop in replacement for MySQL or should i safely go for Mariadb which is a classic SQL fork of the former?

Comment: In a system of any importance or size, *any* change (even from one version of MySQL to another) will require extensive regression testing.

Comment: Agreed. If you are looking for a NewSQL replacement to MySQL, you should also check out ClustrixDB, which has support for views, stored procs, etc. (disclaimer: I work there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuoDB is a viable drop-in here however, I would suggest using v2.0 which is slated for release  mid-October to take advantage of extended View, Stored Procedure functionality, etc.